# How to have two class inherited from pydantic_settings (Base setting), FastAPI

Tags: python, environment-variables, config, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to have two classes inherited from in pydantic_settings BaseSettings.

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(verbose=True)

class Setting(BaseSettings):
     name:str
     age:int
    
     class Config:
         env_file = ".env"
    
settings = Setting()
    
class JWT(BaseSettings):
     s_key:str
     otp:int
    
     class Config:
        env_file = ".env"
    
jwt = JWT()
```

But i am getting this error :

**Extra inputs are not permitted [type=extra_forbidden, input_value='300', input_type=str]**

If i use all variables in single class it works.(my .env has all fields mentioned in this config)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pydantic settings load environment variables automatically and `BaseSettings` does not allow extra fields.
In addition, you should use `SettingsConfigDict` instead of `Config` class after Pydantic V2

```py
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class Setting(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file=".env", extra="ignore")  # see `extra` field. default is `forbid`
    name: str
    age: int

    
settings = Setting()
    
class JWT(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file=".env", extra="allow")  # same here
    s_key: str
    otp: int


jwt = JWT()
```

`extra` can be one of

- `allow`
- `ignore`
- `forbid`; this is default

Here's the actual Pydantic code in [pydantic/config.py](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/aa73451918a0a7f43c240c677ad4c9527a12e253/pydantic/config.py#L26)

```py
ExtraValues = Literal['allow', 'ignore', 'forbid']
```

TL;DR

Set `extra` field in `SettingsConfigDict` except `forbid`.

Ref: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/pydantic_settings/#dotenv-env-support